# Calculating Likelihood Ratio: Uniform vs Other Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be some data observed lying in the unit interval. We want to test the null hypothesis $H_0$ that $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d uniform on the unit interval, versus $H_1$, that $X_1,...,X_n$ are i.i.d with distribution $f(x) = 6x(1-x)$ with $x \in [0,1]$. How would I compute the likelihood ratio for this?

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to come up with a likelihood, as it seems we are no longer estimating a single parameter $\theta$ but now instead estimating a distribution, which seems markedly more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are performing what is called a [*simple hypothesis test*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Simple_hypotheses), which involves comparing two models that are fully specified **a priori** (i.e., **not fitted to the data**, which would require you to take into account model complexity).

Let $\mathcal{L}_1$ be the likelihood of the uniform model, and $\mathcal{L}_2$ be the likelihood of the parabolic model, then:

$$\mathcal{L}_1 = \prod_1^n X_i,\; \;\rm{and}\;\; \mathcal{L}_2 = \prod_1^n 6X_i(1-X_i)$$

You then form the likelihood ratio:

$$\Lambda = \frac{\mathcal{L}_1}{\mathcal{L}_2}$$

You need to pick a value $c \in \mathbb{R^+}$ so that you reject the uniform model in favor of the quadratic model if $\Lambda < c$ and do not reject otherwise.

You will probably need to do some Monte Carlo simulation studies to calculate the null distribution of $\Lambda$ assuming the uniform model is true, so you can set $c$ to give you the desired significance level.

Comment: I see! So usually when I calculate the likelihood for some series of i.i.d R.V.s, it would be of the $L(\theta ;x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n f(x| \theta)$. I guess my question is (speaking definitionally) why are the above functions the likelihood functions in this case?

Comment: @rubikscube09 technically, they are likelihoods (not likelihood functions, since they have no argument). What you are really doing in likelihood approaches is comparing the likelihood of models, not parameters --the parameters merely index the models -- there is a subtle distinction between "the likelihood of $\theta$" and "the likelihood of $f(\theta|x)$. Here, we simply have no free parameters so we don't need the full "function" machinery, but the validity of likelihood methods rests on the likelihood part, not the function part.